# PSD rank 1 matrix decomposition into product of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Assume that I'm given with matrix $\textbf{Q} = \textbf{q}\textbf{q}^H$. Assume I only have $\textbf{Q}$, is there any way for me to find vector $\textbf{q}$?
Thanks!

Comment: You are right, but is there is a way to get this vector up to the phase?

Comment: sorry I deleted my comment by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be such that $x^H Q x > 0$. Then $\dfrac{Qx}{\sqrt{x^H Q x}} = \dfrac{q^H x}{\|q^Hx\|} q = cq$ where $\|c\| = 1.$

Next note if $q \neq 0$ then for some $i$ we must have $ e_i^H Q e_i = || e^H q||^2 = |q_i|^2 > 0$, where $e_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ canonical basis vector and $q=(q_1,\dots,q_n)^T$.

Next note that $q$ can only be determined upto a constant $c$ with $\|c\| = 1$ since $(cq) (cq)^H = \|c\|^2 qq^H = qq^H$ so we can assume wlog $c = 1$ above.

We can choose a $q$ as $\dfrac{Qe_i}{\sqrt{e_i^H Q e_i}}$ for the $e_i$ for which $e_i^H Q e_i > 0.$ If no such $i$ exists we must have $Q =0$ and we can choose $q=0.$

Comment: I have matrix with complex entries. could you show it to me for this case?

Comment: No difference in argument. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Modified answer.

Comment: I need to ask you what is $e_i$? I don't really see an expression for $\textbf{q}$.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: $e_i$ is the vector with $i$th entry $1$ and rest $0$.

Comment: I see your idea... You take the column of the matrix $\textbf{Q}$ and divide it by the module of the corresponding diagonal element(it's absolute value), right?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44288/discussion-between-arin-chaudhuri-and-mykola-servetnyk).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the quickest approach I can think of: let $\mathbf x$ be any non-zero column of $Q$.  Then, it suffices to take
$$
\mathbf q = \frac{\sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(Q)}}{\|\mathbf x\|} \cdot \mathbf x
$$
Note, however, that if $z$ is a complex number with $|z| = 1$, then $(z\mathbf q)(z\mathbf q)^H = \mathbf q \mathbf q^H$.